# I'm checking if the object in nsdictionary is nil and I'm getting wrong response - why?

Tags: ios, swift, nsdictionary

I want to store in `NSUserDefaults` information if user clicked the button or not.
I have two buttons, one has +1 value, the other one -1.

When user presses one of those two buttons, I'm doing this:

```
if (self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons") == nil){
    let currentButtonId:[String:String] = [self.pressedButtons:vote]
    self.defaults.setObject(currentButtonId, forKey: "pressedButtons")
    self.defaults.synchronize()
} else {
    var pressedButtons:[String:String] = self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons") as! [String:String]
    pressedButtons[self.button_id] = vote
    self.defaults.setObject(pressedButtons, forKey: "pressedButtons")
    self.defaults.synchronize() 
}
```

in the code above `vote` is a String value that can be either `"1"` or `"-1"`.

Now, when user comes back to the panel, I'm checking if he already pressed the button or not. This is how I check it:

```
if (self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons") != nil){

    if (self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons")![currentButtonId] != nil) {
        print("user already pressed")
        print(self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons")![currentButtonId])
    } else {
        print("USER didn't press the button yet")
    }
} else {
    print("USER didn't press the button yet for sure") 
}
```

the output that I always see is:

```
user already pressed
nil
```

Since this line:

```
print(self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons")![currentButtonId])
```

prints `nil`, why am I seeing the message that user pressed the button?

Comment: Have you tried seeing what `self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons")` prints?

Comment: Yes I did, so far I have only one record there: `Optional({ 583201282b9b12326fe2fee5 = 1;})`, but the situation happens no matter what id I put in `self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons")![currentButtonId]`

Comment: @user3766930 Can you try what I just posted as an answer

Comment: Do you control the value `583201282b9b12326fe2fee5`? What exactly is `self.pressedButtons` that you store as the string in `[self.pressedButtons:vote]`?

Comment: Guys, @RajanMaheshwari answer worked, I assigned it to a variable and now it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take this object always typecasted as `[String:String]` while fetching

```
let variable = self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons") as! [String:String]
```

Now this is a variable of type `[String:String]`

Now fetch your value accordingly

This doesn't know that  `self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons")` is a object with type `[String:String]`. So, typecast it first and then use. So `self.defaults.objectForKey("pressedButtons")![currentButtonId]` seems to be nil

Comment: Thank you @Rajan, you were right about storing it as a variable, now it works!